# Why does python say that there is an attribute error for cvzone.Classifier()

Tags: python, cvzone

I am trying to make object recognition in python and I am having this error message come up when I run my code:

```
AttributeError: module 'cvzone' has no attribute 'Classifier'
```

This is my code:

```
import cvzone
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
myClassifier = cvzone.Classifier('converted_keras/keras_model.h5','converted_keras/labels.txt')
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: There is no module titled Classifier?

Comment: No, it is supposed to be a part of cvzone.

Comment: I believe the Classifier is in the ClassificationModule, so try ```cvzone.ClassificationModule.Classifier```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `1.5.4` version of cvzone there is no such function called classifier so try installing the `1.3.3` version of cvzone. `pip install cvzone==1.3.3`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

from cvzone.ClassificationModule import Classifier

Then

myClassifier = Classifier('converted_keras/keras_model.h5','converted_keras/labels.txt')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).